# jQuery tooltip plugin to position tooltips based on another div instead of the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I am using [this jQuery tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) to create simple tooltips on various divs of my page. The plugin positions the tooltip relative to the mouse position. Instead, I would like the tooltip to appear centered above the div that was hovered over, unmoving, in the same place every time. Is this possible using this plugin, and if so, could you point me in the right direction? If not, perhaps suggest an alternative?

Here is [a jsFiddle with the sort of setup I have](http://jsfiddle.net/WN4sN/1/). Unfortunately, the styling doesn't really work without the plugin. I hope this code's good enough.

Comment: FYI, not an official plugin - just part of the plugin repository (many different authors).

Comment: @h0tw1r3, ah, right, I'll change it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's something you can do with that jQuery Tooltip plugin.

Some of these look more suitable for that task:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip plugin in question does not appear to support relative positioning.

Qtip does: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/